# Trying to use an input of function_A within another function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I am trying to use an int input from the anual_salary function to calculate an answer for the fed_tax function but I keep getting an error saying the saved variable from function 1 is undefined in function 2.

I understand that salary is locally scoped but I need to use it in the next function along with other functions.

```
def anual_salary():
    salary = int(input("Enter your salary: "))
    print(f"Gross income is ${salary}")
    print(" ")
    return salary

def fed_tax():
    esbi = input("Are you an Employee, Self Employed, Business owner, or Investor? ")
    if esbi == "Employee" or "employee":
        fed_income_tax = .37 * salary
    elif esbi == "Self Employed" or "self employed":
        fed_income_tax = .35 * salary
    elif esbi == "Business owner" or "business owner":
        fed_income_tax = .20 * salary
    elif esbi == "Investor" or "investor":
        fed_income_tax = .15 * salary
    else:
        print("Incorrect answer!")
    fed_income_tax = round(fed_income_tax, 2)
    print(f"Your Federal Income Tax is ${fed_income_tax}")
    print(" ")
    return fed_income_tax
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You never call `anual_salary()`. Where are you trying to use it?

Comment: BTW, `if esbi == "Employee" or "employee":` is wrong. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002503/why-does-a-b-or-c-or-d-always-evaluate-to-true

Comment: And if you do call `annual_salary`, you have to save the return value in a local variable. Just calling the function won't make *its* local variable `salary` available in the current scope.

Comment: Put `salary = anual_salary()` at the beginning of `fed_tax`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `salary` in other functions, you can just call the `annual_salary()`.

```
    def annual_salary():
        salary = int(input("Enter your salary: "))
        print(f"Gross income is ${salary}")
        print(" ")
        return salary

    def fed_tax():
        salary = annual_salary()    # this line calls the annual_salary
        esbi = input("Are you an Employee, Self Employed, Business owner, or Investor? ")
        if esbi == "Employee" or esbi == "employee":
            fed_income_tax = .37 * salary
        elif esbi == "Self Employed" or esbi == "self employed":
            fed_income_tax = .35 * salary
        elif esbi == "Business owner" or esbi == "business owner":
            fed_income_tax = .20 * salary
        elif esbi == "Investor" or esbi == "investor":
            fed_income_tax = .15 * salary
        else:
            print("Incorrect answer!")
        fed_income_tax = round(fed_income_tax, 2)
        print(f"Your Federal Income Tax is ${fed_income_tax}")
        print(" ")
        return fed_income_tax
```

As shown above, whenever you want to use `salary` along with other functions, just need to add `salary=annual_salary()` to call it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the function and store the value in a local variable in fed_tax().

```py
def fed_tax():
    salary = anual_salary()
    esbi = input("Are you an Employee, Self Employed, Business owner, or Investor? ")
    if esbi == "Employee" or "employee":
        fed_income_tax = .37 * salary
    elif esbi == "Self Employed" or "self employed":
        fed_income_tax = .35 * salary
    elif esbi == "Business owner" or "business owner":
        fed_income_tax = .20 * salary
    elif esbi == "Investor" or "investor":
        fed_income_tax = .15 * salary
    else:
        print("Incorrect answer!")
    fed_income_tax = round(fed_income_tax, 2)
    print(f"Your Federal Income Tax is ${fed_income_tax}")
    print(" ")
    return fed_income_tax
```

Answer (score 0):

You are defining a function where you ask for a salary and it is returned, so, what you have to do is that in the function that multiplies said salary, you send to call the class that asks for it, in the following way:

```
def fed_tax():
salary = anual_salary()
esbi = ....
if ....
    fed_income_tax = .37 * salary
elif ...
    fed_income_tax = .35 * salary
elif ....
    fed_income_tax = .20 * salary
elif ....
    fed_income_tax = .15 * salary
else:
    print("Incorrect answer!")
fed_income_tax = round(fed_income_tax, 2)
print(f"Your Federal Income Tax is ${fed_income_tax}")
print(" ")
return fed_income_tax
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the function as part of the if/else and avoid storing it as a separate value

```
def fed_tax():
esbi = input("Are you an Employee, Self Employed, Business owner, or Investor? ")
if esbi == "Employee" or "employee":
    fed_income_tax = 0.37* anual_salary()
elif esbi == "Self Employed" or "self employed":
    fed_income_tax = .35 * anual_salary()
elif esbi == "Business owner" or "business owner":
    fed_income_tax = .20 * anual_salary()
elif esbi == "Investor" or "investor":
    fed_income_tax = .15 * anual_salary()
else:
    print("Incorrect answer!")
fed_income_tax = round(fed_income_tax, 2)
print(f"Your Federal Income Tax is ${fed_income_tax}")
print(" ")
return fed_income_tax
```